# C++ object member integer has ridiculous value (WTF)

Tags: c++, class, object

This is for a poker game and I have class PokerTable defined in PokerTable.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class PokerTable
{
private:
 int numPlayers;
 int numPlaying;
 int dealerPos;
 int bigBlind;
 int potSize;
 int betSize;
 bool flop;
 bool turn;
 bool river;

 public:
 //constructors
 PokerTable();
 PokerTable(int,int,int,int,int,bool,bool,bool);

 //getters
 int getNumPlayers(){return numPlayers;};
 int getDealerPos(){return dealerPos;};
 int getBigBlind(){return bigBlind;};
 int getNumPlaying(){return numPlaying;};
 int getPotSize(){return potSize;};
 int getBetSize(){return betSize;};
 bool getFlop(){return flop;};
 bool getTurn(){return turn;};
 bool getRiver(){return river;};
 //void buttonShow(int);


 //setters
 void setBetSize(int inBetSize){betSize = inBetSize;};
 void setBigBlind(int inBigBlind){bigBlind = inBigBlind;};
 void setNumPlaying(int inNumPlaying){numPlaying = inNumPlaying;};
 void setPotSize(int inPotSize){potSize = inPotSize;};
 void setFlop(bool inFlop){flop = inFlop;};
 void setTurn(bool inTurn){turn = inTurn;};
 void setRiver(bool inRiver){river = inRiver;};
 void setNumPlayers(int inPlayers){numPlayers = inPlayers;};
 void setDealerPos(int inDealerPos){dealerPos = inDealerPos;};
};
PokerTable::PokerTable()
{
 numPlayers = 9;
 numPlaying = 9;
 dealerPos = 1;
 bigBlind = 20;
 flop = false;
 turn = false;
 river = false;
}
PokerTable::PokerTable(int playerNum, int playingCount, int posDealer, int blindBig,int inPotSize, bool inFlop,bool inTurn,bool inRiver)
{
 numPlayers = playerNum;
 numPlaying = playingCount;
 dealerPos = posDealer;
 potSize = inPotSize;
 bigBlind = blindBig;
 flop = inFlop;
 turn = inTurn;
 river = inRiver;
}
```

In my watch list pokerTable.numPlayers has a random value up to 4 million before I even execute this next line of code.

```
PokerTable aPokerTable(9,9,1,20,30,false,false,false);
```

and afterwards here is pokerTable in my watch list:

```
-       aPokerTable { numPlayers=2990892 numPlaying=9 dealerPos=9 ...}  PokerTable
        betSize 30  int
        bigBlind    1   int
        dealerPos   9   int
        flop    false   bool
        numPlayers  2990892 int
        numPlaying  9   int
        potSize 20  int
        river   false   bool
        turn    false   bool
```

Can anyone tell me why all the values are not what I declared them to be??!?!!
And how I can fix this?

This is Form1.h

```
#pragma once
#include "PokerTable.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include <time.h>
#include "PokerPlayer.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

//global variables
//TODO make players start from 0
int firstPlayer;
int deck[52];
int nextCard=0;
PokerTable aPokerTable(9,9,1,20,30,false,false,false);
PokerPlayer players[9]; //however many players
ofstream gameLog;
/*
void setTable()
{
    aPokerTable.setNumPlayers(9);
    aPokerTable.setNumPlaying(9);
    aPokerTable.setDealerPos(1);
    aPokerTable.setBigBlind(20);
    aPokerTable.setPotSize(30);
    aPokerTable.setBetSize(20);
    aPokerTable.setFlop(false);
    aPokerTable.setTurn(false);
    aPokerTable.setRiver(false);

}
*/
string convertInt(int number) //convert to string
{
   stringstream ss;//create a stringstream
   ss << number;//add number to the stream
   return ss.str();//return a string with the contents of the stream
}

void createPlayers()
{
//  aPokerTable.setNumPlayers(9);
    for(int x=0;x<=(aPokerTable.getNumPlayers()-1);x++)
    {
        players[x] = *(new PokerPlayer(1000,(aPokerTable.getDealerPos())+1,false,0,1));//1000 chips, position i+1, not folded
    }
}



void playRound()
{
    int action;
    for(int playerTurn = firstPlayer; playerTurn <= aPokerTable.getNumPlayers()+firstPlayer;  playerTurn++)
    {
        if(players[playerTurn].getFold() == false)
        {
            if(aPokerTable.getNumPlaying() == 1)
            {
                players[playerTurn].setChipStack(players[playerTurn].getChipStack() + aPokerTable.getPotSize()); //player wins pot
            }
            else //there is more than one person playing
                {
                action = players[playerTurn].action(); //0 is check/fold, value is call/bet/raise,
                if(action > aPokerTable.getBetSize())
                {
                    aPokerTable.setBetSize(action);
                    aPokerTable.setPotSize(aPokerTable.getPotSize() + action);
                    playerTurn = playerTurn - aPokerTable.getNumPlayers();
                }
                else if (action == aPokerTable.getBetSize()) //call
                {
                    aPokerTable.setPotSize(aPokerTable.getPotSize() + action);
                }
                else //action < aPokerTable.betSize
                {
                    players[playerTurn].setFold(true);
                    aPokerTable.setNumPlaying(aPokerTable.getNumPlaying()-1); //removes player from playing tally
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


void randomDeck()
{
    int random_integer;
    int tempCard;
    //srand((unsigned)time(0));
    for(int j=0;j<=51;j++)
    {
        deck[j] = j;
    } 

    for(int i=51; i>=1; i--)
    {
        random_integer = rand()%(i); //a random number between 0 and i
        tempCard = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[random_integer]; //put the random card from unshuffled deck into slot i of the deck
        deck[random_integer] = tempCard; //put whatever was at slot i into the random slot
    }

}

void dealCards()
{
    for(int j=1;j<=aPokerTable.getNumPlayers();j++)
    { 
        players[j].setCard1(deck[nextCard]);
        nextCard++;
        players[j].setCard2(deck[nextCard]);
        nextCard++;
    }
}

void playPreFlop()
{
    aPokerTable.setBetSize(aPokerTable.getBigBlind());
    aPokerTable.setFlop(false); //it is before the flop
    aPokerTable.setTurn(false);
    aPokerTable.setRiver(false);
    randomDeck(); //shuffle cards
    dealCards();
    firstPlayer = (aPokerTable.getDealerPos() + 3)%(aPokerTable.getNumPlayers()); // first player is left of blinds between 0 and numplayers
    playRound();
}


void playFlop()
{
    aPokerTable.setFlop(true);
    firstPlayer = (aPokerTable.getDealerPos())%aPokerTable.getNumPlayers(); // first player is left of dealer between 0 and numplayers
    aPokerTable.setBetSize(0);
    playRound();
}
void playTurn()
{
    aPokerTable.setTurn(true);
    firstPlayer = (aPokerTable.getDealerPos())%aPokerTable.getNumPlayers(); // first player is left of dealer between 0 and numplayers
    aPokerTable.setBetSize(0);
    playRound();
}
void playRiver()
{
    aPokerTable.setRiver(true);
    firstPlayer = (aPokerTable.getDealerPos())%(aPokerTable.getNumPlayers()); // first player is left of dealer between 0 and numplayers
    aPokerTable.setBetSize(0);
    playRound();
    if(aPokerTable.getNumPlaying() >=2)
        {
        //showDown();
        }
}
/*
void showDown()
{

}
*/
```

This is pokerPlayer.h

```
using namespace std;
    class PokerPlayer
    {
    private:
        int chipStack,position;
        bool fold;
        int card1,card2;
    public:
        //constructors
        PokerPlayer();
        PokerPlayer(int,int,bool,int,int);

        //getters
        int getChipStack() {return chipStack;}
        int getPosition() {return position;}
        int getCard1(){return card1;}
        int getCard2(){return card2;}
        bool getFold(){return fold;}

        //setters
        void setChipStack(int inChips){chipStack = inChips;}
        void setPosition(int inPos){position = inPos;}
        void setCard1(int inCard1){card1 = inCard1;}
        void setCard2(int inCard2){card2 = inCard2;}
        void setFold(bool inFold){fold = inFold;}

        int action();
    };

    PokerPlayer::PokerPlayer()
    {
        chipStack = 1000;
        position = 0;
        fold=false;
        card1 = 0;
        card2 = 1;
    }
    PokerPlayer::PokerPlayer(int inChipStack,int inPos, bool inFold, int inCard1, int inCard2)
    {
        chipStack = inChipStack;
        position = inPos;
        fold = inFold;
        card1 = inCard1;
        card2 = inCard2;
    }
    int PokerPlayer::action()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this is just a debugger issue? What happens when you print the values manually?

Comment: You're going to need to show us the part of the code that has the bugs in. And you seriously need to re-consider how you name your members and your parameters.

Comment: @dauphic He's calling the constructor which sets 9 parameters.

Comment: @David Heffernan, it only sets 8 variables, though there are 9 in total; one int is uninitialized. It's not the one he says is wrong, however. Something is strange here.

Comment: @dauphic You are right, but that's not the problem.

Comment: `players[x] = *(new PokerPlayer(...` : This is not sane C++. I believe you are thinking in Java and making some similar mistake in your driving code (I guess it's in `main` function here). Can you post those parts? Also where exactly have you stopped your debugger?

Comment: Break points are int nextCard=0; and PokerPlayer players[9]; - so the initialisation of aPokerTable is between them.

Comment: Does the problem persist after you increase the array size of deck to `int deck[100];`, just to add some padding between these variables?

Answer (score 2):

> aPokerTable { numPlayers=2990892 numPlaying=9 dealerPos=9 ...}

Note that dealerPos got assigned the value 9, that's wrong as well.  If you look closely, you'll see that everything is shifted by 4 bytes.

Two possible reasons.  The debugger could have picked the wrong address for aPokerTable, the actual address minus 4.  That's unlikely.  Or there's a mismatch between the definition of the PokerTable class as seen by pokertable.cpp and the other .cpp files that #include the pokertable.h include file.  Where pokertable.cpp saw an extra member before the numPlayers member.  Maybe you edited the header and deleted that member but ended up not recompiling pokertable.cpp for some mysterious reason.  Build + Rebuild to fix.  Do panic a bit if this actually works.

Comment: Excellent pickup on the 4 byte shift.  There is no PokerTable.cpp, only PokerTable.h which is included in Form1.h.  I've rebuilt and it did not help, and I can not seem to find an extra member before numPlayers.  Should I create a PokerTable.cpp file?

Comment: No.  I don't have a clue what could cause the offset.  Copy the project to a file sharing service if you want somebody to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in C++ before the constructor is called, variable uses the value that it already contains in its memory location that is a "random" value

Comment: Do you see the part in the constructor that assigns this particular variable? Also, don't C++ constructors zero-initialize?

Comment: I posted the rest of the code.  This could help.  I am an amateur programmer so any advice would help.

Comment: @David: No, they certainly don't.

Comment: @David Sorry I didn't see the constructor. I can't understand the reason considering that your constructor is assigning parameters to members correctly. However, inc C++ constructor does not assign any values to variables. You should do it yourself. It's not like Java

Comment: I tried using the function setTable which sets all the values independently.  This this not fix the problem

Comment: @Max I compiled and debugged your code until after `PokerTable aPokerTable(9,9,1,20,30,false,false,false);` And all the parameters were correctly assigned except for betSize. Which makes sense since you didn't initialize it by constructor. Are you sure you are reading the value of variables right after constructing? if yes then what compiler are you using? could be an issue with compiler or debugger

Comment: I am using Microsoft visual studio C++ Express.  It is part of a windows form. I could rebuild the code into a console application as it does not need a GUI yet.  If this is the problem can you suggest a compiler?

Comment: @Max I debugged it with VS2010 myself. Using Microsoft VS I really highly doubt it's a compiler issue. No idea sorry!

Comment: @David thank you:| At least this crazy man is trying to help what are you doing other than insulting people?

Comment: @David: Global and static variables are initialized to their default values, but not local variables.

Comment: @amir I suggested that he posted the rest of the code, since the originally posted code would not behave that way. Your answer is correct but not actually the cause of the problem. Suggesting that the compiler might be the problem is not helpful.

Comment: @David He said he debugged and read the values until right after `PokerTable aPokerTable(9,9,1,20,30,false,false,false);` and the funny value appeared right after the previous line of code. I copied and pasted the same code in my compiler and it gives the expected result. Knowing that there are no other threads, what other thing could affect the values? There are many opensource compilers which could be buggy don't you suspect that? or should I shut-up about this possibility because you sir might consider it crazy? I have been here for a short time but man people have big egos here

Comment: @amir Which compilers do you know with bugs in such a fundamentally basic section of C++?

Comment: @David I don't know and I agree that's a very very tiny possibility that we can try to eliminat. We could try that because we don't what other thing causes the problem. Knowing that I did the exact same thing with my compiler and it worked correctly, can you explain that? or do you know what could have gone wrong?

Comment: @amirmonshi maybe I have not installed c++ correctly.  Is there any other installation requirements other than installing VC++?  I am glad to know it works for you.

Comment: @Max I don't think that's the case with MS VC++. It should be working correctly given what you mentioned in your post. We simply have no idea that's why we are fighting:))

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reconstruct it because i dont have the full code. However, a **random value near 4 million** sounds like a pointer. When you store or retrieve a member variable maybe you did not de-reference the pointer. Please post the rest of the code so we can check if that's the case.

Comment: how should I dereference the pointer?  I thought using the constructor auto de-references the variables.

Comment: Not talking about the constructor but about your printing-method

Answer (score 1):

> `players[x] = *(new PokerPlayer(...));`

That is a memory leak. What you probably want is:

```
players[x] = PokerPlayer(1000,(aPokerTable.getDealerPos())+1,false,0,1);
```

Comment: Thank you. I kludged this to get rid of a right operand wrong data type error.  I think the main problem is I do not know C++ well enough